# Disable Onboard Speaker with script for Skype usage

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype

I have Skype and in a private room I use my on-board speaker and onboard d microphone. However, in an open plan office I plug in my Logitech USB headset and I wish to use it as both the speaker and microphone.  Attempting to select this in Skype and skype says they are the same device and will not let this happen
[image]
If I disable the onboard speaker 
[image]

Skype then works with my Headset as both my speaker and microphone although the selection windows appear with no device shown in some of the locations
[image]

Using the GUI works - but is slow so does anyone have a way to disable and re-enable the speaker using a script ?

```
wmic path Win32_PNPEntity where "PNPDeviceID='HDAUDIO\\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0293&SUBSYS_1028062B&REV_1000\\4&2D3AF44E&0&0001'" get Description,PnPDeviceId /format:table
```

Gives me the following

```
Description                    PNPDeviceID
Realtek High Definition Audio  HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0293&SUBSYS_1028062B&REV_1000\4&2D3AF44E&0&0001
```

So the suggested way to locate the device in WMI works however the command

```
wmic path Win32_PNPEntity where "PNPDeviceID='HDAUDIO\\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0293&SUBSYS_1028062B&REV_1000\\4&2D3AF44E&0&0001'" call disable
```

gives

```
disable - Invalid class method.
```

Comment: Use : `wmic path Win32_PNPEntity call /?` and see if `Disable Method` is implemented, also check if the reserved char `&` in your path must be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

**On windows 10** you can use powershell PnpDevice commandlet (require : admin right)

For find your device :

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/get-pnpdevice?view=win10-ps

for disable your device :

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/disable-pnpdevice?view=win10-ps

**On windows 7** (and other)

For find your device name:

> wmic path Win32_PNPEntity get Description,PnPDeviceId /format:table

Disable your device :

> wmic path Win32_PNPEntity where "PNPDeviceID='yourPNPDeviceIDname'" call disable

You can put wmic command in a command file (.bat) and then execute this with admin right.

**NOTE:** if you call PNPDeviceID='yourPNPDeviceIDname' in command line, ensure escape backslash (must be double backslash : '\\ANAME\\ANOTHER...') for yourPNPDeviceIDname